# Is PHP not case sensitive?

Tags: php, forms, case-insensitive

I am using [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). In my database I have this table called `users`, and inside the `users` table have a record:

username: admin

password: password

In my login page, I tried login as (password: password):

- username : ADMIN -> result : can login
- username : admin -> result : can login

I store the username in my database as "admin", all lowercase.

In my PHP authentication page, I didn't include the strtolower() function. Does it mean, in PHP the username form field that I submitted is not case sensitive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not PHP. It's your database query that is not case sensitive.

You can either make one of the operands binary string.  For example:

```
SELECT 'abc' LIKE 'ABC';
```

This will return `1` or `true`.  While

```
SELECT 'abc' LIKE BINARY 'ABC';
```

will return `0` or `false`.

Comment: Yes, MySQL is not case sensitive by default.

Comment: Huh?? Can explain more? My current script: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "'";

Comment: >> How to make it sensitve?? << check my post

Comment: @Narayan: Cant find your post

Comment: @Narayan: Opps, sory, I found it alreay. Its on one of the answers of this question

Comment: Don’t use `LIKE`, use a simple comparison instead.

Comment: @Gumbo: do you mean something like this: SELECT ... 'abc' = 'ABC'

Answer (score 3):

Yup, as Randell said, it's the database that is case-sensitive. Check this article, for *[Can we make MySQL to be case sensitive for SELECT queries and can we force a column in MySQL to be always lowercase?](http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2006/09/case-sensitive-mysql.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

I think have some way to go before it's clear...

MySQL is NOT case sensitive for queries. SELECT and select mean the same thing.

The data in the tables is stored as is, but since you can only get information out with queries, you need to phrase them carefully.

As Randell said

```
select 'abc' like 'ABC'
```

Will return TRUE (so will `SELECT 'abc' like 'ABC'`) because LIKE ignores case differences

```
select 'abc' like binary 'ABC'
```

will return FALSE (and so will `SELECT 'abc' LIKE BINARY 'ABC'`) because LIKE BINARY looks more carefully. There IS a difference at the binary level.

Answer (score 0):

How should it know it's the username form field?

If I remember right, in *nix a username was case-insensitive. Are you using a library to store the userinformation and to compare it?

Comment: i submit the username in 2 versions, 1 in all uppercase, 1 in all lowercase, both can login. No, i didnt use any library, just a simple login form I created by myself

Answer (score -1):

When you are login, I think you should write query  to validate user name and password are the same in the table you have been saved.

Comment: My table stored the username as "admin" (all lowercase), thats mean, in php, i need to use strtolower() to convert all the string to lowercase. Is that what you mean? Based on Randell's answer, its case-insensitive, so why should I use the strtolower() again? What are the causes if I dont use the strtolower() function? Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Your answer has been voted down, does it mean I dont need to convert the string to lowercase?